# Alternative to multinomial logistic regression that doesn't use a reference/baseline?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mathematical-statistics, multinomial-distribution

I am on a project developing a model to predict which of 3 groups customers will belong to.

I am currently using multinomial logistic regression. The three customer groups are the Loyals, who regularly purchase from our company; the Switchers, who sometimes purchase from our company, and the Nevers, who never purchase from our company. The Nevers are currently serving as the reference category in my model.

My current model makes its predictions from 3 variables: customer age, customer rating of our advertising, and customer price sensitivity.

The output shows the following:

[image]

For example, I predicted for a customer who is 38 years old, has a value on the advert variable of 8 and a value on the price variable of 4 and got the following:

[image]

Using this information, how can I calculate the probability of this customer being Loyal? Being Lapsed? Being a Never? I am asking for absolute probability, not the probability of being Loyal vs Never or Lapsed vs Never.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! That seems to be what the model returns: the probability, conditioned on your features taking particular values, of each category. What does that lack that you want? Do you mean converting the odds to probability values?

Comment: Dave, thank you for asking. The current model is using the nevers group as a reference category - it is calculating the probability of being loyal vs a never & a lapsed vs a never.

What I am trying to calculate is absolute probability, not the probability of being Loyal vs Never or Lapsed vs Never.

Comment: How do I calculate the absolute probability of being loyal, how do I calculate it for a "lapsed", and how do I calculate this for a "never"?  I am trying to avoid reference categories which is why multinomial logistic regression doesn't work.

Comment: So if you got the probability parameters of a multinomial distribution, you would be happy? That is, given feature values of whatever, the probability of being NEVER is $0.3$, of LOYAL is $0.2$, and of LAPSED is $0.5$.

Comment: I think that would suffice - I am happy as long as I can calculate the probability of each category without using a reference category. The caveat is that I will need to use input variables like the above (age, advert, price).

Comment: That’s exactly what a multinomial logistic regression gives you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140828/discussion-between-xavier-conzet-and-dave).

Comment: To obtain the probabilities, you must use `predict(..., type="response")`. By default, `predict.gam` returns the linear combination of the predictors ("link value").